# Why is readme saved as .md type on account opening?

Tags: github

I expected .txt.

Will it do any harm to change it to .txt?

I changed it to .txt.

Appeared to do no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is supposed to be written in [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (which has the file extension .md)

Comment: What do you mean? If you use Markdown in the readme it will display it properly on the site of the repository

Comment: I mean if someone downloads my repo to their local system, what app will they use, that will read .md?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Editors) says "_There are a variety of such editors available for all of the major platforms_", I guess you have to google it for your OS

Comment: html/css is the only markdown/up I plan on learning...no time.